# Duplicate package problem

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jar

I am trying to integrate Twitter in my application. I import two .jar files with different names, but one package has the same name in both files. When I compile, it shoes following error.

> Description Resource Path Location Type
>   D:\CustomClasses\ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2.jar(org/kxml2/io/KXmlParser.class): Error!: Duplicate definition for 'org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser' found in: org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two JARs are third party (not platform libraries), you should consider a more sophisticated compilation and packaging step. But before going down this path, check to see whether the JARs you are importing don't come in different forms -- ones that don't embed their dependencies.

Either way, have a step in your compilation to extract just the parts that you need from each JAR.

If you are not using build scripts but use an IDE for everything, set up a build script just to build your customized dependencies JAR.

Comment: thanq u sir, here now i took only uesfull packeges from both jar file and make it as a new jarfile with different name. now it is not showing any compile time error but at run time it shows " Error starting 'Myproject': Module 'MyProject' has verification errors"